# JAWS announces document after tabbing to the next element after an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, jaws-screen-reader

Currently working on a web application that uses an iFrame.

Once i navigate to the next element after the iFrame, which is a button, has type=“button”, and the word ‘Cancel’ in it, JAWS  announces ‘Cancel, Document’.

I have looked all over and can’t seem to find anything on this issue, not sure what would fix it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.